# Non duplicate numbers

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am making a C# script in visual studio for windows forms.
I need to get non duplicated numbers and that is what I have tried in that script, what happens is that when i compile the project, I get this random numbers, but sometimes, those numbers are duplicated, so I would like if you tell me which mistake I have made, or even if the mistake is in that piece of code.
I need to store this random numbers from 1 to 75 to say if these 75 created random numbers, compared with a table with some numbers that I already have are equal.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 76; i++)
        {
            auxiliar = random.Next(1, 75);
            bool continuar = false;

            while (!continuar)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= contador; j++)
                {
                    if (auxiliar.ToString() == totalBalotas[j])
                    {
                        continuar = true;
                        j = contador;
                    }
                }
                if (continuar)
                {
                    auxiliar = random.Next(1, 75);
                    devuelve = auxiliar.ToString();
                    continuar = false;
                    estaContando = true;
                    return devuelve;
                }
                else
                {
                    continuar = true;
                    totalBalotas[contador] = auxiliar.ToString();
                    devuelve = auxiliar.ToString();
                    contador++;
                    estaContando = true;
                    return devuelve;
                }
            }
        }
        estaContando = true;
        return devuelve;
    }
```

This is the code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7wqk.png

Comment: The script is on here https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcxIl.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't forget to include your code in your question. You can [edit] the question. We strongly discourage showing code or data in images.  Cut and paste **the text** of your code into the question, and indent it by four spaces.

Comment: It can't be a random number if duplicates are not allowed.  Google "c# random shuffle" to get ahead.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question *as text*.

Comment: That code makes no sense to me.  Post code not an image.

Comment: "I am making a C# script" ... so show us . BTW C# is not script

Comment: I've removed your visual studio tag because this question isn't related to visual studio (the development environment)

Comment: @JacekCz It depends on context.  Unity tends to refer to C# files as "scripts" in its documentation, so many Unity developers tend to use the same terminology.  What's important is that we understood what the OP meant by "script".

Comment: Why are you generating 76 numbers from 1 to 75? Are you trying to rearrange the numbers from 1 to 75 in a random order? That is a shuffle, not random.

Comment: Build a list with your numbers 1-75 and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt) to shuffle it.

Answer (score -1):

Could you say what is the purpose for generating non duplicate numbers? Should these numbers be random? Are there any boundaries on these numbers?

What I can think of right now is using Random to generate numbers and store already used numbers in a collection to avoid duplicates.

Here is example of class that provides unique random numbers. You can think about making it static and threadsafe if you have need for it.

```
class NonDuplicateRandomNumbersGenerator
{
    private Random r = new Random();
    private ISet<int> usedNumbers = new HashSet<int>();

    public int NonDuplicateRandomNumber()
    {
        var number = r.Next();

        while (usedNumbers.Contains(number))
        {
            number = r.Next();
        }

        usedNumbers.Add(number);
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: And simply generating the numbers 1-75 and shuffling them isn't a better option?

Comment: Hi, look... I need to make a Bingo, I need to store this random numbers from 1 to 75 to say if these 75 created random numbers, compared with a table with some numbers that  I already have are equal... Thanks for the answer...

Comment: @Nicolas you should have told us that to start with. This answer will not do what you want; you want a shuffle as explained in john's comment.

Answer (score -2):

i can understand a little what you are trying to explain, when generating random numbers these can be repeated if you want to generate non-repeated randoms you will have to compare with the whole list of numbers already generated by each generated number.

Comment: No, you generate ordered numbers and then shuffle them.